# How to access files stored in AzureDataLake and use this file as input to AzureBatchStep in azure.pipleline.step?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I registered an Azure data lake datastore as in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore.datastore?view=azure-ml-py#register-azure-data-lake-workspace--datastore-name--store-name--tenant-id--client-id--client-secret--resource-url-none--authority-url-none--subscription-id-none--resource-group-none--overwrite-false-) in order to access the files stored in it.

I used

```
DataReference(datastore, data_reference_name=None, path_on_datastore=None, mode='mount', path_on_compute=None, overwrite=False)
```

and used it as input to azure pipeline step in [`AzureBatchStep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.azurebatch_step.azurebatchstep?view=azure-ml-py) method.

But I got an issue: that datastore name could not be fetched in input.
Is Azure Data Lake not accessible in Azure ML or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please follow the guideline before asking your question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Lake is not supported as an input in AzureBatchStep. You should probably use a [DataTransferStep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.data_transfer_step.datatransferstep?view=azure-ml-py) to copy data from ADL to Blob and then use the output of the DataTransferStep as an input to AzureBatchStep.